# C++: "switch" on actual type given pointer to superclass

Tags: c++, polymorphism, rtti

Say I have a class called `Message` with subclasses `MessageA`, `MessageB` ... `MessageZ`.

Maybe these messages are in a heterogeneous queue, and I'm dequeuing them, and I'm positive their parent type is Message but that's all I know.

An old C programmer might put a field in Message that is basically an enum for the message type, so I could do something like:

```
switch ( message.ActualMessageType ) {
MessageAType:
   blah blah A
   break;
MessageBType:
   blah blah B
   break;
 :
 :
MessageZType:
   blah blah Z
   break;
}
```

That's a hassle though: as I add message subclasses, I have to keep editing that master enum definition file.

With C++99 I might put give Message a pure virtual method called BlahBlah(), and have each subclass define it appropriately.  Then instead I'm writing:

```
message.BlahBlah();
```

Nice because it may be faster to call a virtual function than do the switch (typically implemented as a lookup table of jumps, but with range checks).

But let's say this blah blah more cleanly belongs in the class with the switch, not the messages who shouldn't need to know the details of how they're processed by this particular class.  Has C++11 (or newer dialects?) added any interesting way to jump directly to processing the various sub-message types?

For instance if I call a templatized function, that has implementations for MessageA and MessageB, with a pointer to Message, whose object is really a MessageA or MessageB, call the right function?

Comment: Shouldn't you just call a virtual function to do the processing?

Comment: Virtual methods are your friends.

Comment: Not sure I entirely understand the problem your trying to solve but you might want to look at the [visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) or [`std::variant`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) and [`std::visit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit).

Comment: It appears you are on the cusp to discover the benefit of `virtual` methods.

Comment: You can give the Message class a member that is a std::function and 'attach' the handler to the message.  Then each message can have a different handler.

Comment: @NicolBolas, and others, I'm not sure why you're suggesting virtual functions when that is the exact example I gave for C++99 in my query.

Comment: @ttemple, OK, so I would write the std::function in the class which would otherwise have the switch, so the code would be in the file it belonged in... and the messages would (somewhere, somehow) have their std::function set to the appropriate one, allowing the msg's function to be called instead of the switch?  It sounds pretty good, except that the same problem still exists: I then have to have a switch (or something) to set that std::function variable in the first place.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I cannot imagine why you're suggesting I consider virtual methods, when the previous comment makes the same suggestion, and both of you are ignoring the half of my original post that specifically discusses virtual methods.

Comment: @Eljay, why are you suggesting virtual methods immediately after two other people suggest the same thing and nearly half of my original posted query discusses virtual methods?

Comment: @SwissFrank • I had posted my comment about at the same time as the other comments.  The other people did not suggest the same thing.  Your original post seemed to have just about worked out why virtual methods are beneficial over the switch/case solution.

Comment: @SwissFrank - it would be up to the entity that instantiated the message class to attach the handler.  you would call the handler when you dequeue the message.  Maybe you don't have control over the creation of the message classes, in which case this is not feasible.  One of the benefits of using attached functions is that they can be changed at run time if there are benefits to doing so.  i.e. you could have some number of handlers, and attach them as needed to different message classes, even at runtime.

Comment: On second thought, the switch statement looks pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

I think there might be a better solution but here's a C++99 solution.

`Message` class has a pure virtual method `BlahBlah( Processor* )`.

The `Processor` that otherwise would need a switch statement will have methods called `BlahBlahA( MessageA* pmsga )`, `BlahBlahB( MessageB* pmsgb )`, ... `BlahBlahZ( MessageZ* pmsgz )` that take a pointer to the message type in question

The subclass `MessageA` would define:

```
virtual void BlahBlah( Processor* pproc ) { pproc->BlahBlahA( this ); };
```

The `Processor` class, at the point it wanted to do the message-class-specific processing, would call:

```
pmsg->BlahBlah( this );
```

That calls the per-subclass definition of `BlahBlah()`, which calls the corresponding method back on the `Processor` class.

Benefits:

1. no global enum needs to be maintained
2. all code for processing is in Processor, not in Message subclasses
3. no switch required.
4. no casts, RTTI, etc. required

Drawback:

1. two virtual function calls impose some kind of overhead.

Comment: Why not just have the message call the processor function, instead of queuing the message and having the processor tell the message to call the callback function?

Comment: @ttemple There are lots of different kinds of objects and messages, some that can process or be processed instantly, and some that take quite a while.  The thread creating these messages, were it to simply call the handlers, would delay delivery to other processors if one processor were slow to process.